# How to show and hide with jquery bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i am able to show hidden DIV  when i click to select item2 with id= 1 and i need if i click to item 0 of id =0  hide again the shown DIV.

```
 div class="ddl-select input-group-btn">
 <select id="search-engine-combobox" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-style="btn btn-default " onchange="showDiv(this)" >
              <option value="0">All Banks</option>  
              <option value="1">Bank Type</option>  
            </select>
          </div>

 <div class="form-group " id="hidden_div" style="display: none;" >

  <select id="banktype"  class="selectpicker show-tick bank-type">
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">Microfinance</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">Home loan</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">certificate deposit</option>
  </select>
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
function showDiv(elem){
   if(elem.value == 1)
     document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "block";
   }
  else if (elem.value == 0) {}{
  ???????
   }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below which is what you expected I hope :-)

```html
<div class="ddl-select input-group-btn">
 <select id="search-engine-combobox" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-style="btn btn-default " onchange="showDiv(this)" >
              <option value="0">All Banks</option>  
              <option value="1">Bank Type</option>  
            </select>
          </div>

 <div class="form-group " id="hidden_div" style="display: none;" >

  <select id="banktype"  class="selectpicker show-tick bank-type">
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">Microfinance</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">Home loan</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">certificate deposit</option>
  </select>
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
function showDiv(elem){
  var targetElm = document.getElementById('hidden_div');
   if(elem.value == 1) {
     targetElm.style.display = "block";
   }
  else if (elem.value == 0) {
     targetElm.style.display = "none";
   }
  
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: @KaberaMugwanezaAlexis Great :-)

Comment: May I know who down voted this and the reason after user accepted?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";`

Comment: It is not working for me and it disables  also to show hidden DIV (hidden_div)

Comment: please check for other errors like misplaced curly brackets or so. Notice this is the same as the accepted answer, but just limited to what you asked, and not other issues